# How to achieve a mixed chart of 'horizontal' bars and line chart using Chart.js?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, chart.js, chart.js2

With vertical bars apparently the whole Mixed Chart renders fine. But when I do it `horizontally` with `two X Axes and one Y Axis`, only the bars would appear but the line chart wouldn't. I have looked at other questions but none of them discussed about this specifically.

[This is what I want to achieve using Chart.js](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/bar-and-line-chart-mix/)

Also for some reason, I had to provide `type: 'linear'` for `scales.xAxes` where `id: 'maturity'` (as shown in the code below) for some reason, otherwise the string labels on Y Axis would also repeat themselves as X axis labels too

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
let chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'horizontalBar',
  data: {
    labels: ['Information Security', 'Asset Management', 'Human Resource Security', 'Physical Security', 'Equipment Security', 'Access Management', 'Review', "Policy Governance", 'Security Coordination', 'label10', 'label11', 'label12', 'label13'],
    datasets: [{
        xAxisID: 'compliance', // X axis 1
        data: [25, 15, 25, 25, 45, 15, 25, 25, 25, 25, 80, 80, 80],
        label: "Compliance",
        backgroundColor: "#3367D6",
        borderColor: 'rgba(105,159,177,1)',
        categoryPercentage: 0.8,
      },
      {
        type: 'line', // line type dataset
        xAxisID: 'maturity', // X axis 2
        data: [4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 5, 4],
        label: "Threshold for Maturity",
        backgroundColor: "rgba(247, 148, 30, 1)",
        borderColor: 'rgba(247, 148, 30, 1)',
        fill: false,
      },
      {
        xAxisID: 'maturity', // X axis 2
        data: [2, 4, 3, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 5, 4, 4, 3],
        label: "Maturity level",
        backgroundColor: "#F7941E",
        borderColor: 'rgba(77,20,96,1)',
        categoryPercentage: 0.8,
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    legend: {
      align: 'end',
      labels: {
        usePointStyle: true
      },
      position: 'top'
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        fontStyle: 'bold',
        ticks: {
          fontSize: 11,
        },
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        },
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Domains',
          fontStyle: 'bold',
          fontSize: 15
        }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        id: 'compliance',
        position: 'top',
        ticks: {
          beginsAtZero: true,
          min: 0,
          stepSize: 25
        },
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        },
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Compliance %',
          fontStyle: 'bold',
          fontSize: 15
        }
      }, {
        id: 'maturity',
        type: 'linear',
        position: 'bottom',
        ticks: {
          min: 1,
          max: 5,
          stepSize: 1,
          callback: function(value, index, values) {
            return 'L' + value;
          },
          fontStyle: 'bold'
        },
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Maturity Level',
          fontStyle: 'bold',
          fontSize: 15
        }
      }]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<canvas class="chart" height="250px" id="myChart"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is, its trying to use labels for x-axis and data for y-axis.

For Chart.js v2.x you could try supplying the data for the line as array of objects: `[{x: 4, y: 'Information Security'}, {x: ...`, I think that should work.

In v3 (still in beta), there is no `horizontalBar` chart type. Instead, there is a new option `indexAxis`, that works for all chart types. [migration guide to v3](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/getting-started/v3-migration)

Here is how you could do it using v3:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
let chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['Information Security', 'Asset Management', 'Human Resource Security', 'Physical Security', 'Equipment Security', 'Access Management', 'Review', "Policy Governance", 'Security Coordination', 'label10', 'label11', 'label12', 'label13'],
    datasets: [{
        xAxisID: 'compliance', // X axis 1
        data: [25, 15, 25, 25, 45, 15, 25, 25, 25, 25, 80, 80, 80],
        label: "Compliance",
        backgroundColor: "#3367D6",
        borderColor: 'rgba(105,159,177,1)',
        categoryPercentage: 0.8,
      },
      {
        type: 'line', // line type dataset
        xAxisID: 'compliance', // X axis 2
        data: [4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 5, 4],
        label: "Threshold for Maturity",
        backgroundColor: "rgba(247, 148, 30, 1)",
        borderColor: 'rgba(247, 148, 30, 1)',
        fill: false
      },
      {
        xAxisID: 'maturity', // X axis 2
        data: [2, 4, 3, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 5, 4, 4, 3],
        label: "Maturity level",
        backgroundColor: "#F7941E",
        borderColor: 'rgba(77,20,96,1)',
        categoryPercentage: 0.8,
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    indexAxis: 'y', // this changes the orientation for all datasets in v3
    responsive: true,
    legend: {
      align: 'end',
      labels: {
        usePointStyle: true
      },
      position: 'top'
    },
    scales: {
      y: {
        fontStyle: 'bold',
        ticks: {
          fontSize: 11,
        },
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        },
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Domains',
          font: {
            style: 'bold',
            size: 15
          }
        }
      },
      compliance: {
        position: 'top',
        beginsAtZero: true,
        min: 0,
        ticks: {
          stepSize: 25
        },
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        },
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Compliance %',
          font: {
            style: 'bold',
            size: 15
          }
        }
      },
      matyrity: {
        type: 'linear',
        position: 'bottom',
        min: 1,
        max: 5,
        ticks: {
          stepSize: 1,
          callback: function(value, index, values) {
            return 'L' + value;
          },
          font: {
            style: 'bold'
          }
        },
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Maturity Level',
          font: {
            style: 'bold',
            size: 15
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.0.0-beta.6/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas class="chart" height="250px" id="myChart"></canvas>
```

Comment: Hello good sir, thank you so much. I'm glad you made the time to reply to my query. The first solution didn't work for me. If it helps - inside of my line `data` array, `x` is coming from a service call and `y` is coming from another service call but I guess not it's causing any issue. I'm yet to try migration to v3 though

Comment: migration to v3 was causing problems. I uninstalled stable version and included CDN in the index.html file of my Angular project but it won't take ctx as valid argument, and caused other problems too, so I have rolled back to stable v2.9.4 and I still don't get line chart to render